# Renaming a file source

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I've been developing an SSIS package from a flat file source. The file comes daily and the file name has datetime indication like this:

Filename_20190509042908.txt

I was wondering how I can pass until the date part; I want the package to read the file dynamically, but it should pass without the last 6 digits I just don't need the last 6 digit numbers as it is not consistent.

I want to pass Filename_20190509.txt

I have figured out how to take the filename until date removing the time part. Hence, I've trouble to let the package read the file name dynamically by ignoring the last 6 digits before file extension.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: What do you mean how can you pass until the date part? Pass what, to where?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the last 6 characters from the file name before the extension? If so, with what, an SSIS expression?

Comment: Edited the question. I want the package to read the file dynamically. But to do so, it should be without the last 6 digits.

Comment: Use a Foreach Loop Container with a wildcard?

Comment: @Larnu I know how to take the filename until date removing the time part. Hence, I've trouble to let the package read the file name dynamically by ignoring the last 6 digits before file extension.

Answer (score 1):

### Remove the time part from the full file path

*Assuming that the full file path is stored within a variable named `@[User::FilePath]`*

You have to add a variable of type string (example: `@[User::Filename]`), Before the data flow task **add an `Expression Task`** and use the following expression:

```
@[User::Filename] = SUBSTRING(@[User::FilePath], 1, LEN(@[User::FilePath]) - 
FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FilePath]), "\\", 1)) + "\\" + 
LEFT(TOKEN(@[User::FilePath],"\\",TOKENCOUNT(@[User::FilePath],"\\")),
LEN(TOKEN(@[User::FilePath],"\\",TOKENCOUNT(@[User::FilePath],"\\"))) - 10) + ".txt"
```

*Example:*

If the value of `@[User::FilePath]` is

> C:\New Folder\1\Filename_20190503001221.txt

Then `@[User::Filename]` will be:

> C:\New Folder\1\Filename_20190503.txt

---

If You have only the file name as

> filename_20190503001221.txt

and the folder path is stored in another variable, just use the following expression:

```
@[User::Filename] = @[User::Folderpath] + "\\" + 
LEFT(TOKEN(@[User::FilePath],"\\",TOKENCOUNT(@[User::FilePath],"\\")),
LEN(TOKEN(@[User::FilePath],"\\",TOKENCOUNT(@[User::FilePath],"\\"))) - 10) + ".txt"
```

### Read File Source from Variable

Click on the flat file connection manager used to read the source file, press <kbd>F4</kbd> to show the properties tab, Click on the expression property and assign the following expression to the `connectionstring` property:

```
@[User::Filename]
```

Now change the *Data Flow Task* `Delay validation` property value  to `True`.

- [Dynamic Flat File Connections in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1084/dynamic-flat-file-connections-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume you are using a foreach loop already as the filename is changing but here is how to change the fully qualified name to what you want:

```
TOKEN(character_expression, delimiter_string, occurrence)
```

Your usage:

this will get you the full filename:

```
exp = TOKEN(@filename,"\",LEN(@filename)-LEN(replace(@filename,"\",""))
```

then from there you need use left plus add .txt

```
left(exp,LEN(exp)-10) + ".txt"
```

Comment: thanks though. I have figured out how to take the filename until date removing the time part. Hence, I've trouble to let the package read the file name dynamically by ignoring the last 6 digits before file extension.